# Братец и сестрица

Tags: морфология, история

По словарю русских суффиксов И. Гаршина

> Суффикс -ец образует существительные со значением:
>   1. лица по принадлежности к стране, территории, городу, где оно проживает или откуда происходит (испанец, новгородец, горец); для женщин - -к- (испанка, новгородка) или -ян-к- (горянка);
>   2. лица, характеризующегося каким-либо свойством (мудрец, глупец, упрямец);
>   3. предмета или явления, характеризующегося признаком или действием, названным словами, от которых они образованы (резец, рубец, холодец).

А суффикс -иц

> 1. названия самок животных (волчица, львица);
> 2. название ягоды (по её
>      свойству: кислица).

Какую фунцию несут эти суффиксы в словах *братец* и *сестрица*. По идее, первоначально эти слова должны были бы относиться к названным или сводным братьям и сёстрам, но подтверждение этой гипотезе найти пока не могу. Так ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> По идее, первоначально эти слова должны были бы относиться к названным или сводным братьям и сёстрам,

Мне непонятна эта идея.
Лисица - сводная сестра лисы?
Песец - брат псу?

Вот обратное, что варианты с суффиксами стали использоваться для подчеркивания ненастоящести, названности отношений - это вполне могу представить. Как вторичное использование. В таком случае получается,  что -ец и -иц здесь изначально выступает в роли ласкательного суффикса (не уменьшительного), но это-то как раз вполне соответствует общим представлениям об этих суффиксах.

Братец лист и братец кролик...
Три сестрицы под окном... 
*Случайно ли тут **сестрицы**? Если учесть, что скоро оказывается, что младшую там явно недолюбливают?*

Answer (score 1):

Это суффиксы с уменьшительно-ласкательным значением или уменьшительно-уничижительным значением, сопровождающимся сильной экспрессией близости, сочувствия или издёвки (бра́тец, вопро́сец, изъя́нец, моро́зец, наро́дец, сюже́тец и т.п.).
Суффикс-ец пишется в словах мужского рода, суффикс-иц в словах женского рода.

Answer (score 1):

> Какую функцию несут эти суффиксы в словах *братец* и *сестрица*?

Из словаря Ефремовой:

> **-ец-**
>
> III суффикс Формообразовательная единица, образующая имена
>   существительные мужского рода с уменьшительно-ласкательным или
>   уменьшительно-уничижительным значением, сопровождающимся сильной
>   экспрессией сочувствия или издёвки *(**бра́тец**, вопро́сец, изъя́нец,
>   моро́зец, наро́дец, сюже́тец и т.п.).*
>
> http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136080

===

> **-иц-(а)**
>
> II суффикс Формообразовательная единица, образующая имена
>   существительные женского рода с уменьшительно-ласкательным, только с
>   уменьшительным или только с ласкательным значением *(вещи́ца,
>   земли́ца, коси́ца, лу́жица, **сестри́ца** и т.п.).*
>
> http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/136225/%D0%B8%D1%86